# Sql lite - date calculation result is in year only

Tags: sqlite

I have col1 with date inserted values... YYYY-MM-DD

I am trying to do simple date calculation with returning days

```
select current_date - col1 from my_table;
```

This result calculates only years, but i am trying to get only days since two dates. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compute the number of days since the signing of the US Declaration of Independence.

```
SELECT julianday('now') - julianday('1776-07-04');
```

from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

So you should be able to write something like this

```
select julianday('now') - julianday( col1 ) from my_table;
```